# Webpack 4 static assets not reloading with HtmlWebpackPlugin

Tags: webpack, html-webpack-plugin, webpack-4

I am configuring a simple webpack 4 setup using npm and HtmlWebpackPlugin to generate an index.html and it all works well, except it only generates the file when running my production build, and changes to the template are not automatically reflected in the browser.

This is my webpack.config.js file

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

// Static data
const castingteamData = require('./castingteam.json');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/app/app.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    publicPath: '/dist/',
    filename: 'build.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
  ..................................omitted loaders
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      data: castingteamData,
      template: 'src/app/index.html'
    })
  ],

  devServer: {
    contentBase: './dist',
    historyApiFallback: true,
    noInfo: true,
    overlay: true
  },
  performance: {
    hints: false
  },
  devtool: '#eval-source-map'
};

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  module.exports.devtool = '#source-map'
  // http://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/workflow/production.html
  module.exports.plugins = (module.exports.plugins || []).concat([
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([
      {
        from: 'src/assets/img/',
        to: 'assets/img/',
        toType: 'dir'
      }
    ]),
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([
      {
        from: 'src/assets/fonts',
        to: 'assets/fonts',
        toType: 'dir'
      }
    ]),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        NODE_ENV: '"production"'
      }
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      sourceMap: true,
      compress: {
        warnings: false
      }
    }),
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      minimize: true
    })
  ])
}
```

In package.json I have these two scripts:

```
"scripts": {
  "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --progress --hide- 
 modules",
  "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --open --hot"
}
```

Like I said the index.html is correctly generated when running npm run build, but no joy with npm run dev. It seems like this should be an easy fix but I can't find it!

Comment: Seems like html files are not being tracked by webpack dev server like js and css files are. Javascript and css changes are immediately reflected in the browser, but after a change in the html template, I need to refresh the browser. Is that just how it is or can it be set up more conveniently?